# Converting Sybase Database to MSSQL Database Error loading database objects Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant

Tags: sql-server, sybase, data-conversion

I have been attempting to use the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase version 6.0 to migrate my Sybase databases to SQL Server. However, I have one database that in the UI shows “Error occurred while loading database objects”, using the console version of the tool shows “FATALERR One of more objects specified as a command params were not found in metabase: .dbo” (and yes the error says “One of more” not “One or more”). All other databases load fine. I ran this tool using the console in the hopes of seeing a more verbose error, but the error still does not tell me why that database’s objects cannot be loaded.

In the following link Microsoft states what sys objects in Sybase I need at least public rights on.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302811(v=sql.110).aspx

The account I'm using is the SA account for the Sybase server so the user account has the appropriate rights. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using the MSSMA console. I've used it to convert many oracle databases. However, there is this peculiar database where one table "attributes" is not getting "Converted" when I do the other "convert-schema" The other tables are getting converted except this one. Don't know what to do.

Comment: In my case it was for Sybase to SQL, I opened up a case with Microsoft, they had me put the conversion tool on a workstation other than the one I have my management studio, i guess the thinking is that there are data access libraries that conflict. When I did that everything worked, but Microsoft did not change the tool to give any better logging to tell me what the actual problem was.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem! I needed to escape the name of the table object. So inside of the script.xml that is the argument for the console mssma exe to run, I used this:
<convert-schema>
<metabase-object object-name="MyDatabase.&quot;ATTRIBUTES&quot;" object-type="Tables"/>
</convert-schema>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an incident with Microsoft, their recommendation was to run the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) from a workstation that did not have Microsoft SQL Server installed on the same machine. This fixed the problem, however there was no mention on the SSMA download site stating that the Migration Assistant needs to run on a separate computer. In addition, the error message could have been more verbose letting me know what the problem was instead of costing me one of my two annually allotted Microsoft incidents.